# wxPython: Initialize class for the main window

Tags: input

I am trying to disable the interface from re-sizing, note that the interface has lots of widgets and panels already.

To my understanding, I can disable re-sizing with the following line of code:

```
wx.Frame(parent, style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE ^ wx.RESIZE_BORDER)
```

However, I have created the code based on the following format:

```
def main():
   ex = wx.App()
   MainWindow(None)
   ex.MainLoop()

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
      ...
```

How should I edit the code to mention that re-sizing is not allowed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you should be able to just replace one line of code:

```
#was: MainWindow(None)
MainWindow(None, style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE ^ wx.RESIZE_BORDER)
```

Comment: I realize this extends to another problem. I need the window to be maximized. So if I disable resizing, then I must use wx.MAXIMIZE but it does not work on Linux.

Comment: MainWindow(None, style = wx.MAXIMIZE | wx.MAXIMIZE_BOX | wx.SYSTEM_MENU | wx.CAPTION | wx.CLOSE_BOX | wx.CLIP_CHILDREN)